# Validation of R for Pharma

Tags: r, validation

This is a non-technical question but I hope that it is OK to ask here.

Statistical software used in Pharmaceutical quality systems require validation for their intended use. I suppose that this applies to R. I have looked around and only found *ValidR* by Mango Solutions fits this requirement. Do you have any experience of validating the R packages that you use in Pharma by yourself or using a third party to do it for you? As for Mango Solution, has anyone experience of using their product? What are their costs, do they validate individual packages or only sell the whole validated software?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about regulated use of R, not programming; it would be on-topic on the `r-help@r-project.org` mailing list.

Comment: from Mango's [web page](https://www.mango-solutions.com/additional-solutions/validr): "We believe that the ValidR product includes the best-performing R packages, but we understand that organisations may require certain packages for specialised tasks. As such, we provide a validation service for additional packages, charged on a time-and-materials basis." I think contacting them would be the best way to answer your second question ...

Comment: For R and SAS, "Validated" and "Warranty" are used interchangeably. FDA will accept submissions in R. The expectation is that if you send the code to the FDA that they can replicate your data and results. If they can't do it, they would need an explanation. For SAS, in the highly unlikely situation that this happened, they would send SAS experts to come and help with the problem. R would not.

Answer (score 5):

I work in the Pharma industry, and while I haven't validated R and it's packages, I have been the technical lead of applications that needed to be validated software. We did it ourselves and it's mainly a documentation exercise, and it's a huge pain in the butt. Basically you need to have test cases that are signed off with the usual stuff that you would put into a unit test, and you need to show before hand what the code paths are, and that all of the code paths have been tested with both positive and negative input. For statistical software, you could show that the output matches whatever you get from SAS (which is validated) I'm not sure however whether that impacts any licensing agreements that you have with SAS.

ValidR only validates the base R and a select number of packages. So if you download another package not included, you're no longer in a validated environment. So if you only use their packages, you're good. If you need anything else from CRAN, then you're no longer validated.

Comment: what a weird world. makes sense on some level i suppose, but is it specific functions that get validated or entire packages?? like what prevents someone from just writing a function using only base R and then calling that (presumably non-validated) function in/for your analysis?

Comment: The entire package is generally validated. But what you're really after is validating all of the functions within that package. As for your second question, the code that you write must also be validated. So if you're doing regulatory filings in SAS, you have to go through the same process with the statistical code  that you write. However, it's easier to validate the code for the statistical analysis plan if your underlying functions like the t-test are already validated

Comment: Sorry for splitting this, but it's a more complex answer. I will ask what exactly are you doing? A lot of research work can be done in non-validated system, provided that once you want to take the results into a regulatory filing, you need to repeat it within a validated system (from a data science point of view, underlying pipelines for getting data from instruments and that kind of stuff will). However, it's a descent trade-off to make since maybe 90% of the work that you do is exploratory and may not go anywhere

Comment: super interesting, thx for the info! a side of the stat computing world im not very familiar with